# Prove that if $p$ is a prime number then $\binom{p-1}{k}\equiv (-1)^k\pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that if $p$ is a prime number then $\binom{p-1}{k}\equiv (-1)^k\pmod{p}$. What can be said about $\binom{p+1}{k} \pmod{p}$?

I thought about expanding $\dbinom{p-1}{k} = \dfrac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-1-k)!}$, but I don't see how that helps. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Hint:  $1+x^p=(1+x)^p=(1+x)^{p-1}(1+x) \pmod p$.  Then proceed inductively.

Comment: You're on the right track, just do some cancellation on $(p-1)!/(p-1-k)!$ and then compare the numerator and denominator.

Comment: How about induction on $k$?

Comment: **Hint:** Wilson's Theorem.  Also, $p-j\equiv -j\pmod{p}$.

Comment: @Batominovski What about the second expression?

Comment: $\binom{p}{k}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for $1 \leq k \leq p-1.$ Your row is immediately above!

Comment: Wilson theorem is not really needed for this one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $k=0$ then it is trivially true. Otherwise:

$$\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-1-k)!}\equiv\frac{(p-1)\ldots(p-k)}{k!}\equiv\frac{(-1)\ldots(-k)}{1\ldots k}\equiv (-1)^k \frac{k!}{k!}\equiv(-1)^k,$$

with the appearance of divisions making sense because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field.

Comment: You don't need to make a separate case for $k=0$ since $0! = 1$.

Comment: @user19405892 Yes, but I felt that the formula $(p-1)\ldots (p-k)$ for $k=0$, although understanable by convention as $1$, would need some (this) explanation, which I thought messier than just discarding the $k=0$ case.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to show that
$$\binom{p}{k}\equiv 0\pmod{p} $$
unless $k\in\{0,p\}$: in such cases $\binom{p}{k}=1$. Now just exploit the fact that:
$$ \binom{p}{k}=\binom{p-1}{k-1}+\binom{p-1}{k} $$
through induction. With the same approach we have
$$ \binom{p+1}{k}\equiv 0\pmod{p} $$
unless $k\in\{0,1,p,p+1\}$: in such cases $\binom{p+1}{k}\equiv 1\!\pmod{p}$.

Comment: What about the second expression?

Comment: @user19405892: it is well-known and easy to prove.

Comment: I am talking about in my question.

Comment: @user19405892: The $(p+1)$-th row of the Pascal triangle $\!\!\pmod{p}$ is $1\; 1\; 0\; \ldots 0\; 1\; 1$ by the same argument.

Comment: So it's not $(-1)^k$ or something similar? It is the Legendre symbol?

Comment: @user19405892: there is no Legendre symbol here, we are dealing with binomial coefficients. Please read my answer carefully.

Comment: I understand your answer. I am asking about $\binom{p+1}{k} \pmod p$. What is the explicit formula for that?

Comment: @user19405892: just written.